# Add records to Ext.data.ArrayStore

Tags: javascript, json, extjs, extjs4

How can I add the following records (from the alert) into the Ext.data.ArrayStore?  The commented out code (in newStore assignment) shows what data is set in the store originally and seems to work.  The code in the loop shows what I've tried that did not work.

```
        var newStore = new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
            fields: [
                'id',
                'value'

            ]
            //data: [[1, 'x'], [2, 'y']]
        });

        //alert(records.toSource());

        Ext.each(records, function(rec) {
            alert(rec.get('id') + ' ... ' + rec.get('value'));
            //newStore.data.add(rec);
            //Ext.apply(newStore, rec);
        });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.add()` expect a record object.  If your objects in the `Ext.each()` are in the format

```
{
   id:"~~", 
   value:"~~"
}
```

simply calling `newStore.add(rec);` will work just fine.

If they are not you will need to build a psudo record by doing something like this:

```
Ext.each(records,function(rec){ 
     newStore.add({id:rec.id,value:rec.value}); 
}
```

Here is a fiddle of a working example

http://jsfiddle.net/7a86L/

Answer (score 1):

```
var arrayData = [
['Jay Garcia', 'MD'],
['Aaron Baker', 'VA'],
['Susan Smith', 'DC'],
['Mary Stein', 'DE'],
['Bryan Shanley', 'NJ'],
['Nyri Selgado', 'CA']
];
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.ArrayStore', {
data : arrayData,
fields : ['personName', 'state']
});



console.log(store.first().data)
```